# timeout or memory leak while running GridSearchCV

Tags: python-3.x, keras, scikit-learn, gridsearchcv

I'm running GridSearchCV from sklearn to fine-tune my keras Sequential NN. I started with `n_jobs = -1` but now I'm using `n_jobs = 2`. My PC has 8 processors but I'm still getting the message:

```
UserWarning: A worker stopped while some jobs were given to the executor. This can be caused by a too short worker timeout or by a memory leak.
  "timeout or by a memory leak."
```

Even so, the GridSearchCV was completed. I'm just curious about why I keep getting this message and if it might mean the results are not reliable.

Comment: Any update / did you find a fix or workaround,  or an answer to your reliability question?

Comment: Actually here you go - does not _seem_ to affect reliability - https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/14626#issuecomment-520659817